# Rails and inserting polygon data (geojson) to the postgis table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

I'm struggling with inserting geoJSON polygon data into postgis table. PostGis working fine. I can execute this query from PG client but it doesn't work from app in rails.

**The insert query in my model in rails:**

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.AddNew(id_partner, route_name, polygon, active)

    sql = "INSERT INTO routes('idPartner', 'name', 'polygon', 'active') VALUES ('#{id_partner}', '#{route_name}', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('#{polygon}'),4326), '#{active}')"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
 end
end
```

**and I'm constantly getting:**

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'idPartner'" LINE 1: INSERT INTO routes('idPartner', 'name', 'polygon', 'active')... ^ : INSERT INTO routes('idPartner', 'name', 'polygon', 'active') VALUES ('8', 'Dara', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"POLYGON","id":null,"coordinates":[[[19.00634765625,52.736291655910925],[22.1484375,52.133488040771475],[22.236328125,52.8823912222619]]]}'),4326), '1')
```

**Table structure:**

```
-- Table: public.routes

CREATE TABLE public.routes
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('routes_id_seq'::regclass),
  "idPartner" integer,
  name character varying,
  polygon geometry(Geometry,4326),
  active integer,
  CONSTRAINT routes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.routes
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query has problems. First, the name of `colums` not match the SQL syntax. Second, the parameter `polygon` is not correct, you must transform the `srid` by using the function transform `grid`, for example `ST_SetSRID`. You could check by run SQL in postgresql example

```
INSERT INTO routes("idPartner", name, polygon, active) VALUES ('8', 'Dara', ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
    '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[19.00634765625,52.736291655910925],[22.1484375,52.133488040771475],[22.236328125,52.8823912222619]]]}'
),4326), '1');
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment Garf! I fix the query and remove the apostrophe in columns name and now it's working properly. Many thanks!